# Search text file for string and copy it's line to another file

Tags: c, file, sorting

I have an array full of surnames. I want my program to use these surnames as follows:

- Search two files, and if at a given point the surname is found in either, copy the other details on that line, and print them to a sorted file.

The surnames are alphabetically sorted. I am using fscanf to read the information and then using strcmp to see if the string is the same, but when I run the program it just copies one students name to the file and nothing else. Here is the code I am using:

```
for(i=0; i<SURNAMES; i++)
{
    //Search file 1
    while (fscanf(fp, "%d %s %s %s",&student_id,first_name,surname,student_type) != EOF)
    {
            if(strcmp(surnames[i], surname) == 0)
            {
                fprintf(sorted_students, "%d %s %s %s\n",student_id,first_name,surname,student_type);
            }
    }

    //Search file 2
    while (fscanf(fp2, "%d %s %s %s",&student_id,first_name,surname,student_type) != EOF)
    {
            if(strcmp(surnames[i], surname) == 0)
            {
                fprintf(sorted_students, "%d %s %s %s\n",student_id,first_name,surname,student_type);
            }
    }

}
```

It somehow works when I put the for loop within the while loop, however when I do this, students that may originally be in the second file are ignored. If I put the for loop inside, the whole idea of alphabetically sorting the students is lost and they are not sorted according to their position in the original array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should go at the first of files, in the first of "for loop" every time!
Use fseek function.

```
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
fseek(fp2, 0, SEEK_SET);
```

Comment: I'm not really sure where you mean.

Comment: Yes, because every time you go to the end of files to search them completely. So, you should go at the first every time.